# How to manage java threads by sleep function?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, jung2

I am impelementing an interface by **JUNG** library for moving `agents`(that are JUNG nodes) between nodes.

When I command the `agent` to move from node **1** to node **2** , and before the agent's trip to node **2** has finished I command the `agent` to move to node **1**.

I want the `agent` to move to node **1** after reaching node **2** But Instead the agent gets `slowed down` ( Because the new command decreases its speed) and when reaches node **2** by that decreased speed it returns to node 1 by the same decreased speed.

And when there is a `Third` node That the agent is commanded to move to (when it is on the trip form node **1** to node **2**) the agent `looses its path` to node **2** and doesn't reach any of the nodes **2** or **3**.

I know this happens because when some `thread` is `moving the agent` the other thread that is performing the new command should somehow become `paused` and after the other `thread` finishes its job it should be `resumed`.

I have tried doing such thing by sleeping the thread but it does't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete implementation of my code `(The main part for moving the agents is the MOVE class)`:

**[InterpretMaster.java](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4a71)**

**[commandMaster.java](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4a72)**

**[Command.java](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4a73)**

**Move.java:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package interpreter.command;
import GraphHandling.BehGraphUndirected;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.AbstractLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.util.IterativeProcess;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationImageServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.ISOMLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.util.Animator;
import interpreter.Command;
import interpreter.CommandMaster;
import interpreter.InterpretMaster;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Move extends Command{

    private CommandMaster cm;
    private BehGraphUndirected behGraph;
    private static String lastAgent = "";

    @Override
    public Object run(BehGraphUndirected behGraph, VisualizationImageServer panel, InterpretMaster interpretMaster,LinkedList<String> nodeList,LinkedList<InterpretMaster.nodeAttribute> nodeAttributes,AbstractLayout <String, String> layout, String... args) {
        System.out.print("move Runs\n");
        this.cm = new CommandMaster();
        this.behGraph = behGraph;
        //AbstractLayout <String, String> moveLayout;

        if(cm.exists(args[0]))
        {
            //got to another command
        }
        else
        {
            switch (args[0]) 
            {
                case "agent":
                    int size=nodeAttributes.size();
                    int i;
                    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
                    {
                        if(args[1].equals(nodeAttributes.get(i).nodeName))
                        {
                            if(nodeAttributes.get(i).isMoving)
                            {

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(Move.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            }
                            VertexCollider vtxCol = new VertexCollider(layout, panel,args[1], args[2] , args[1] , nodeAttributes.get(i));
                            vtxCol.setMaximumIterations(1000);
                            vtxCol.setDesiredPrecision(1);
                            vtxCol.initialize();
                            Animator animator = new Animator(vtxCol);
                            animator.start();
                            nodeAttributes.get(i).isMoving = true;
                            break;  
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        interpretMaster.repaint();
        return null; 
    }


    class  VertexCollider extends IterativeProcess
    {
        private String COLLIDER;
        private AbstractLayout<String, String> layout;
        private VisualizationImageServer<String, String> vv;
        private Point2D startLocation;
        private Point2D endLocation;
        private Double moveX;
        private Double moveY;
        private InterpretMaster.nodeAttribute agentAttributes;

        public VertexCollider(AbstractLayout<String, String> layout, VisualizationImageServer <String, String> vv, String vertexA, String vertexB , String collider , InterpretMaster.nodeAttribute nodeAttributes) {

            this.layout = layout;
            this.vv = vv;
            startLocation = layout.transform(vertexA);
            endLocation = layout.transform(vertexB);
            COLLIDER = collider;
            agentAttributes = nodeAttributes;

        }

        public void initialize() {
            setPrecision(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            //layout.setLocation(COLLIDER, startLocation);
            moveX = (endLocation.getX() - startLocation.getX()) / getMaximumIterations();
            moveY = (endLocation.getY() - startLocation.getY()) / getMaximumIterations();
        }

        @Override
        public void step() {
            layout.setLocation(COLLIDER, layout.getX(COLLIDER) + moveX, layout.getY(COLLIDER) + moveY);
            vv.repaint();
            setPrecision(Math.max(Math.abs(endLocation.getX() - layout.transform(COLLIDER).getX()),
                Math.abs(endLocation.getY() - layout.transform(COLLIDER).getY())));
            if (hasConverged()){
                //layout.getGraph().removeVertex(COLLIDER);
                agentAttributes.isMoving = false;
                System.out.println("reached");


            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[Create.java](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4a6e)**

Comment: This is far too much code for this site. I have not looked at it. But from your problem statement, the node movement is **sequential**, and requests to move nodes should be processed **sequentially**. If this is the case, I would suggest a very simple producer/consumer pattern, with a single "node mover" thread that takes movement events from a queue. Any number of other threads deposit these events in the queue. Some sort of concurrent, FIFO, queue should work fine - consider a [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have added the complete implementation just in case it's needed for understanding the code.

Comment: No, that is not how this site works. You need to create an SSCCE that **illustrates your problem**. That we can analyse, and if necessary, run. Posting massive amounts of code is unhelpful, and will likely lead to downvotes for you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know what you are mentioning about the consumer and producer problem I have Implemented such code before but this code has different implementation and I don't know how to create and manage threads for it.

Comment: and also I don't want to limit the program in moving multiple agents at the same time.